# Excel weeknum function showing wrong week number?

Tags: excel, week-number

I have a workbook:

```
Column A       Column B
01/01/2017     =WEEKNUM(A2,2)
26/01/2017     =WEEKNUM(A3,2)
```

I am trying to get the week number starting monday.
Excel gives me this:

```
01/01/2017      1
26/01/2017      1
```

Both dates cannot have a week number of 1. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Hard to say as I cannot replicate it.  I get `5`.  Try hitting F9, maybe your calculations are set to manual.

Comment: I get 1 and 5. Note that your second date should be MM/DD/YYYY, in this case 01/26/2017.

Comment: @VBAPete only if their local setting are that way.  Most countries are DD/MM/YYYY as their standard short date.

Comment: @VBAPete No i don't believe in US dates haha

Comment: @VBAPete my dates/settings are configured to uk type

Comment: @ScottCraner But wouldn't format then be DD.MM.YYYY? I thought the / / always indicates an American style date.

Comment: Oh I see, learned something new :)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same concern and stumbled on this thread too (Microsoft Excel Online).

For this case, ISOWEEKNUM worked for me, please note that I've set my date settings to English (United Stated).

Comment: A code example would be helpful to show exactly what you mean. Please include the input fields as well as the formula you used. That way formatting etc. are clear.

Answer (score 0):

As long as there is no precise answer for this post, I would like to mention that your issue is all documented in [WEEKNUM](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/weeknum-function-e5c43a03-b4ab-426c-b411-b18c13c75340?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us).

> There are two systems used for this function:
>
> System 1    The week containing January 1 is the first week of the
> year, and is numbered week 1.
>
> System 2    The week containing the first Thursday of the year is the
> first week of the year, and is numbered as week 1. This system is the
> methodology specified in ISO 8601, which is commonly known as the
> European week numbering system.
>
> Syntax `WEEKNUM(serial_number,[return_type])`

```
Return_type  Week begins on  System 
...
21           Monday          2
```

Given this,

```
=WEEKNUM("26/01/2017",21)
```

Will calculate as defined in ISO 8601 since `Return_type` 21 is the only one with System 2.

---

[ISOWEEKNUM](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/isoweeknum-function-1c2d0afe-d25b-4ab1-8894-8d0520e90e0e?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us)

```
=ISOWEEKNUM("26/01/2017")
```

Will also do it.